# Perl print to STDOUT is garbled

Tags: string, perl, printing, quotes

I suspect this a "quotes" problem but I cannot figure it out. I have a perl script that reads a file containing pairs of strings separated by a user defined delimiter. Call this the "replacement file". The script first loads the list of pairs and then reads an input file.

Examining the input file, each string on the LHS of the delimiter in the replacement file (call this `srchString`) is replaced by the corresponding string on the RHS (call this `replString`). The result is written to an output file. The substitution can be case sensitive or case insensitive.

In order to allow users to specify certain special characters, I have accommodated the use of some standard character entities from XML, including `&apos;` and `&quot;`. The `srchString` & `replString` are defined using these entities.

Now I want to stress at this point that the substitution part works! Case sensitive or case insensitive, I get exactly the results I want in my output file. Where I'm having difficulty is in the report at the end. I want to write out a report that shows the number of times each search-string was replaced. I do this in a loop which is the one shown below. You can see how many variations I've tried, but I always get the same garbled result. (I tried making some other changes to make sure I was running the correct version code, so that is not the problem).

My replacement file (swSpec.txt):

```
swap&nbsp;&quot;IT&quot;;x:with&nbsp;&apos;Repl&apos;
abc;x:xyz
Banana;x:Mango
```

My input file (testInput.txt):

```
Test 1 : swap "it"
Test 2 : swap "IT"
Test 3 : swap it
Test 4 : abc
Test 5 : ABC
Test 6 : Have a 'Banana' split
Test 7 : Have a 'BANANA' split
```

For the sake of completeness, a case sensitive swap gives the following output (testOutput.txt):

```
Test 1 : swap "it"
Test 2 : with 'Repl'
Test 3 : swap it
Test 4 : xyz
Test 5 : ABC
Test 6 : Have a 'Mango' split
Test 7 : Have a 'BANANA' split
```

In my test I deliberately used a pretty weird delimiter - `;x:`.

The report I get looks like this:

```
' in 1 line(s).swap "IT"' (case sesitive) replaced by 'with 'Repl'
' in 1 line(s).abc' (case sesitive) replaced by 'xyz
testInput.txt:'Banana' (case sesitive) replaced by 'Mango' in 1 line(s).
```

The code that produces this report (5 earlier attempts are commented out):

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < $numSwap; $i++) {

  print STDOUT $fil2;
  print STDOUT ":\'";
  print STDOUT $srchList[$i];
  print STDOUT "\' ";
  print STDOUT $caseString;
  print STDOUT " replaced by \'";
  print STDOUT $replList[$i];
  print STDOUT "\' in ";
  print STDOUT $countList[$i];
  print STDOUT " line(s).\n";

  ## 5th change
  #$s1 = $srchList[$i];
  #$s2 = $replList[$i];
  #$d1 = $countList[$i];

  #$rptString = "$fil2: &apos;$s1&apos; $caseString replaced by &apos;".
  #             "$s2&apos; in $d1 line(s).\n";
  #print STDOUT substEntities($rptString);

  ## 4th change
  #$rptString = $fil2.": &apos;".$s1."&apos; ".$caseString." replaced by &apos;".
  #             $s2."&apos; in ".$d1." line(s).\n";
  #print STDOUT substEntities($rptString);

  ## 3rd change
  #$rptString .= ":\'";
  #$rptString .= $srchList[$i];
  #$rptString .= "\' ";
  #$rptString .= $caseString;
  #$rptString .= " replaced by \'";
  #$rptString .= $replList[$i];
  #$rptString .= "\' in ";
  #$rptString .= $countList[$i];
  #$rptString .= " line(s).\n";
  #print STDOUT $rptString;

  ## 2nd change
  #$rptString = $fil2.": '".$srchList[$i]."' ".$caseString." replaced by '".
  #             $replList[$i]."' in ".$countList[$i]." line(s).\n";
  #print STDOUT $rptString;

  ## 1st change
  #$rptString = $fil2.": \'".$srchList[$i]."\' ".$caseString." replaced by \'".
  #             $replList[$i]."\' in ".$countList[$i]." line(s).\n";
  #print STDOUT $rptString;

}
```

Originally I printed the report using a single interpolated string with quotes around it. That gave the same result as all of the above attempts with some minor variations that I deliberately introduced.

By way of explanation, `substEntities()` is the subroutine I use to make the replacement of the `&quot;` etc, in my `srchString` and `replString`.

Note that the last line of the report is correct. That's what I want.

Is there a simple way to get the report to print sensibly? or should I reverse the `substEntities()` action before writing the report? Any hints?

Comment: Try `printf STDOUT qq{%s:'%s' replaced by '%s' in %d lines.\n}, $fil2, $srchList[$i], $caseString, $countList[$i];` instead of your `print` lines. Should not change anything. But still curious.

Comment: You don't have to print to STDOUT unless you've been messing around with `select` to change the default print file handle. Also, no need to escape single quote, or break up strings to interpolate variables.

Comment: Try printing your variables with `Data::Dumper`, using the useqq option to print out whitespace in literal form. `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $replList[$i]` I suspect you may find that your string contains `\r`, which is left over after using `chomp` on a file with CRLF endings.

Comment: @TLP; Your suspicion was right on the money! I had been editing my input data on Windows machine using pspad, but I was saving the data on a Samba drive and testing under Linux. On Windows using Active Perl, `chomp()` will remove CRLF, but under Linux the CR remains. I explicitly set pspad to use Unix line feed and PRESTO! It now works as desired. Thank you so much. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. It's a common problem here on stackoverflow.com. And it is a pretty baffling problem the first time you encounter it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this so others won't need to go through the comments.

The input data was edited on a Windows machine with an editor (PSPad) using CRLF. The tests were performed on a Linux machine. It is common to use `chomp()` to remove the line feeds before manipulating text. However, under Linux only the LF (\n) is removed, the CR (\r) remains. The result was the messy output you see above.

The solution was to edit the text and specify Unix line feeds. Most editors, including PSPad, have this facility.